# Why doesn't eclipse notice I have updated Java

Tags: java

I downloaded eclipse but it said I was running the wrong java as in I was running java 6 VM and it required a java 7 VM but I updated to java 7 and re-ran the program and it still said I was running Java 6. Please help, Im probably missing something very simple but don't realize it yet.

Comment: Did you set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to your Java 7 installation?

Comment: Is this Windows, Mac or Linux (or *other*)? What is the result of `java -version`?

Comment: At this point, you really should be using Java 8, if you are interested in learning Java, since it includes some new features that are designed to make coding some things cleaner/easier. Newer versions of Eclipse also support Java 8 directly.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the java on your project properly.
Right click on your project and choose properties and on the opening dialog choose java build path as picture below

[image]

then choose libraries tab and click on you JRE/JDK and hit the edit button to change the JDK/JRE
as picture below

[image]

If you have your desired java version in the drop down select that otherwise click on installed JREs and add your desired JRE/JDK path

[image]

and then hit OK and save the project.
You should be good after eclipse rebuilds the project